# Retrieve unpublished videos on Dailymotion API

Tags: php, dailymotion-api

I'm trying to retrieve the **unpublished videos** I have on my DM account, i.e. the videos I've uploaded to DM but are not yet public. I'm using the PHP SDK v1.6.3 and I'm quite a beginner with the Dailymotion API.

I assume (but I'm not 100% sure) that I have to use the **private filter** as documented [here](https://developer.dailymotion.com/documentation#video-filters)

I've tried

```
$api->get('/me/videos',array('filters' => array('private')));
```

which raises a **DailymotionApiException** exception with the following message

> Unrecognized value (private), allowed values are (featured, hd,
>   official, creative, creative-official, ugc, buzz, buzz-premium, 3d,
>   live, live-offair, game, all-live, live-upcoming, no-live, premium,
>   premium-paidvideos, premium-offers, no-premium, history, with-poster,
>   without-poster, promoted-on-games) at index #0 for `filters' parameter

which is strange because from [this doc](https://developer.dailymotion.com/documentation#video-filters), 'private' is a valid filter for videos.

I've also tried

```
$api->get('/me/videos',array('filters' => array('private' => true)));
```

which apparently has a wrong format as it also raises a **DailymotionApiException** exception

> Invalid type (array required, dict given) for `filters' parameter

Is there something wrong with the way I use filters in the PHP SDK ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 mistakes in what you do:

- first, "private" is different from "unpublished"
- they way you call the filters is not the right one.

1) A **private** video is only viewable by you on dailymotion as it does not appear on your channel page. You can share it with other users by sharing the private permalink that you can retrieve using the `url` field.

An **unpublished** video is only viewable by you and can't be shared. It should be used when you edit the video (description, title, etc) before publishing it.

2) Now, about the way you call the PHP SDK: 
`private` is a filter by itself, you don't need to add the `filters` parameter. The `filters` filter is deprecated (see https://developer.dailymotion.com/documentation#video-filters-filter).

Your call has to be using either of: [`flags=private`](https://developer.dailymotion.com/documentation#video-flags-filter) or: [`private`](https://developer.dailymotion.com/documentation#video-private-filter) filter.
With the PHP SDK, you could use:

```
$result = $api->get('/me/videos',array('flags' => array('private')));
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I was indeed confused with the difference between "unpublished" and "private".

The PHP code sample you provided works fine for returning private videos. But how do i get the unpublished videos (which is the thing I wanted to do in the the first place) ? The 'unpublished' flag isn't recognized.

Comment: yes, we do not have such thing as an unpublished flag. I suggest you to check the `published` field for each of your video if you really need to.

Comment: @Dailymotion if you execute the test below into your browser https://api.dailymotion.com/videos?private=1&tags=chwing you can see that private parameter 1 or 0 don't change the return numbers videos, why ? (url generate from https://developer.dailymotion.com/tools/apiexplorer#/video/list)

Comment: you need to be authenticated to see private videos (otherwise the ywould not be private) so you need to pass an access token @stloc

Comment: @Dailymotion I use PHP SDK with GET /me/videos so I think I am authenticaded